# How to understand Ubuntu and become developer

Tags: command-line, application-development

Can you guys tell me, how to become a Pro Ubuntu User?
Where did you guys learnt all this from? Which book or which Programming language have you all learnt?
I also want to learn how to build applications and run codes etc. (Just like you all)
I have learnt Java and Shell Scripting (All at basic level), and currently I am learning C++.

Comment: Learn Python and C++ . Solve problems on AskUbuntu. Developer is a problem-solver

Comment: It's taken me 50 years to get to where I am, and you want a quick summary/shortcut?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to become a master in Ubuntu, simply follow these steps:

1. Make a backup of your system.
2. Experiment with things.
3. Break your system.
4. Restore from backup.
5. Jump to step 2.

---

In all seriousness, there's no "one" way to master an operating system and everything that it's made of. It takes a lot of practice, experience, time, and effort to even get halfway good at it, and there will *always* be someone better.

Snoop around this site and the wikis. Pick up tips. Learn from those who are better. Teach those who aren't as skilled as you. Eventually, you'll become another one of the greats.

Comment: @HenryWHHackv2.0 I'd count that as a backup.

Comment: If it aint broke, break it.